# Compare firstpart of x2 text box contents

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm hoping somebody can help here.
I have x2 text boxes that data is inputted by a user, once the second box has data I then send to a Label click. (Windows mobile)
The Label click will compare both boxes, but I only want to check the first 4 characters. this is where I'm stuck.. I'm assuming I may need to send both entries to a string of some kind?

The current code for compare

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles LinkLabel1.Click

If Textbox1.Text = Textbox2.Text then

Do something
```

Comment: You can use .substing for example.

Comment: Sorry,
How do you mean?

Comment: Microsoft provides documentation of .Net classes and methods. For example [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: Thanks been reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with Substring with your example :

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles LinkLabel1.Click

If Textbox1.Text.Substring(0, 4) = Textbox2.Text.Substring(0, 4) then

Do something
```

Comment: Great thanks! Now it seems I need to compare 4 characters when it starts with a letter and not the initial first 4 characters!

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way in the end..

On the keydown of each text box  -

Private Sub Txtboxbcpb_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Txtboxbcpb.KeyDown

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

Dim str As String = Txtboxbcpb.Text.Substring(0, 4)

Txtboxbcpb.Text = str

So it stripped them and placed back into the text box. then I ran the compare action

However, I now need to strip the input from when the first letter starts then 4 from there. any ideas?
Appreciate all your help ;-)

Jonny